# How can I retrieve the confirmation ID for a US visa application appointment?

Tags: visas, usa

I submitted and booked a visa appointment but accidentally lost my appointment ID, and I need to change my appointment date. Is there a way to retrieve my appointment confirmation ID (not the barcode number)?

I'm applying from Mauritius for a tourism visa to visit the US

Comment: Which visa are you applying for?

Comment: We can not read minds and this is a world wide site. Which country did you apply for a visa for, where are you based and what kind of visa?

Comment: My bad. It’s a us visa

Comment: In what country are you applying for the visa?